# How to select only table rows with specific content inside

Tags: css, ruby, nokogiri

I'm scraping an email that has many table rows, some of which I want to exclude. The table rows I do need look *exactly* like:

```html
<tr>
  <td class="quantity"> ANYTHING BUT EMPTY </td>
  <td class="description"> ANYTHING BUT EMPTY </td>
  <td class="price"> ANYTHING BUT EMPTY </td>
</tr>
```

None of the table rows have a class or id. Moreover, there are unwanted `<table>` rows that contain cells with these classes but some with no values, so I need to get only table rows that have these three classes of cells, and all three cells with non-empty values. I'm not sure of the syntax to do this:

```ruby
body = Nokogiri::HTML(email)
wanted_rows = body.css('tr').select{ NOT SURE HOW TO ENCAPSULATE LOGIC HERE }
```

Comment: Usually you do `select { |e| ... }` where there's some method call on your element `e` that means something. For example, `e.html.match(/\S/)` to test for at least one non-space character.

Comment: I understand how .select and iterators in general work, I'm just not sure how to encapsulate the logic for only selecting table rows that contain non-empty cells with the appropriate classes

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking a question like this, it'd help us if you'd provide a better example of the HTML that has the minimum data to demonstrate the problem, such as two lines containing data and one that doesn't. "[mcve]" talks about this. The more you help us up front, the faster we can help you and the more accurate your question and data, the more accurate we can be. It helps you to help us in other words. We *can* do the extra work to adjust the input, but that slows us and actually discourages help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward with XPath:

```ruby
wanted_rows = body.xpath('//tr[td[(@class = "quantity") and normalize-space()]
  and td[(@class = "description") and normalize-space()]
  and td[(@class = "price") and normalize-space()]]')
```

The `normalize-space()` calls are effectively the same as `normalize-space(.) != ""`, i.e. they check that the current node (the `td`) contains something other than just whitespace.

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much. Just tried it out, and it works. Now time to go read up on XPath...